# ¿Por qué los valores de los nodos son 0?

Tags: c++

Soy nuevo en C++ y estoy tratando de crear una clase que emule una Singly Linked List (no sé el nombre en español). Tengo una serie de nodos con punteros al siguiente en la memoria y con un determinado valor. Ya implementé métodos como el de agregar un valor al final de la lista, y estoy trabajando en la representación en la consola de esta estructura.

El problema es que al intentar hacer un loop a través de los nodos me encuentro que todos son 0. Jugando algo más con el código, me di cuenta que esto también sucede en el método AppendNode().

**SLList.h**

```
#include "Node.h"

class SLList
{
private:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;

public:
    SLList();
    SLList(Node head);
    ~SLList();

    // Methods

    void AppendNode(int val);
    void RemoveNode(int val);

    void Show();
};
```

**SLList.cpp**

```
#include "SLList.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

SLList::SLList()
{
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}

void SLList::AppendNode(int val)
{
    Node *n = new Node(val);
    n->next = NULL;

    cout << n->val;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = n;
        tail = n;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = n;
        tail = n;
    }
}
void SLList::Show()
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        cout << "SLL ["
             << "]" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        string out;
        Node *curr_node = head;

        while (curr_node != NULL)
        {
            out += to_string(curr_node->val);
            curr_node = curr_node->next;
        }
        cout << "SLL [" << out
             << "]" << endl;
    }
}

SLList::~SLList() = default;
```

**Node.h**

```
class Node
{
public:
    int val;
    Node *next;
    Node(int val);
    ~Node();
};
```

**Node.cpp**

```
#include "Node.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Node::Node(int val)
{
    val = val;
}

Node::~Node() = default;
```

**Program.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

#include "SLList.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SLList my_list;

    my_list.AppendNode(2);
    my_list.AppendNode(3);
    my_list.AppendNode(4);
    my_list.AppendNode(4);
    my_list.AppendNode(4);
    my_list.AppendNode(4);

    my_list.Show();

    return 0;
}
```

Los métodos my_list.Show() y el cout que implementé para hacer el debugging retornan solo ceros, a pesar de que les inciailice el valor a un 4, por ejemplo. Estoy confundido, ¿tendrá algo que ver con los punteros?

Comment: Creo que copiaste el contenido de `Node.h` como `Node.cpp`.

Comment: Corregido, me pasa por usar la extensión de VIm

Comment: _Lista Simplemente Enlazada_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en como asignas el valor del miembro `val` en `Node.cpp` (tienes un parámetro con el mismo nombre que el miembro de tu clase), así:

```
Node::Node(int val)
{
    val = val;
}
```

Cámbialo por algo como:

**Node.cpp**

```
Node::Node(int newVal)
{
    val = newVal;
}
```

**Node.h**

```
class Node
{
public:
    int val;
    Node *next;
    Node(int newVal);
    ~Node();
};
```

### **Update:**

También puedes usar el puntero `this`, así:

```
Node::Node(int val)
{
    this->val = val;
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Qué error tan tonto de mi parte